# Is declaring multiple instances of the same class/DAO in a Spring Boot project harmful?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm just starting to pick up Spring, coming from a purely Java EE background, so stuff like IOC and dependency injection is all kinda new to me. As per the Spring docs, I understand that for any class to call on instances of its dependencies, I can choose to autowire those dependencies as a form of dependency injection. And that this is actually aside from the usual instance declaration we always do in java like below: `Animal animal1 = new Animal()`

In my one of my little test Spring boot project services, I noticed that I end up doing **both** dependency injection and normal class instantiation. I use JPA Repository to craft my repo layer, and autowire the repo classes so I can use them like eg.

```
@Autowired 
customerAccountRepo
```

This is all fine. I also have a DAO `customerMembershipValidity` whose attributes are other declared POJOs and has some public helper functions within to set the DAO's attributes. In order to use this DAO, however, I find myself creating multiple instances of the DAO the traditional way, instantiating 
`CustomerMembershipValidity customerMembershipValidity1 = new CustomerMembershipValidity()` multiple times throughout the service to call on public helper methods like `customerMembershipValidity.setNewExpiry()`. I didnt think there would be a need to autowire this since I'm dealing with a DAO or POJO, not another service... or should I?

For now, the code seems functional when I do my unit-testing, but I would like to know if this would harm the overall longevity and sensibility of the code, or if it's forseeable to end up breaking in E2E when I run the Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few recommendations:

1. DAO should be a singleton Spring Bean that you inject into service bean(s) that need it.  Make sure there is no mutable shared state in your DAO - just database operations.
2. The DAOs I write might use mapper functions to map ResultSet to objects/collections, but I don't see the need for helpers.
3. Spring preference is to use constructor injection.  You should not use setter or autowired attribute to inject dependencies.
4. If you use new, that means the object is not under Spring's control.  It's appropriate to call new for objects in method scope, but not a Spring Bean like a DAO.
5. Unit testing and production are two different things.  I prefer to leave Spring out of unit testing.  I call new for JUnit tests, but not production code.  Once I've tested the DAO, I can use mocks for services that depend on it.

You're smart to take up Spring and leave Java EE behind.  It's a twenty year old dead standard.